# using manually html in winRT webView class

Tags: c++, webview, windows-runtime

I am porting a program to winRT.
I have a webview (Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::WebView) for displaying manually builded hmtl-Text. Some Text comes from our newsserver via HttpClient (using Windows::Web::Http::HttpClient class), the other part is the hardcoded formating of the html, like the body, a banner gfx and the pfad of the .css file.

My Problem is how can i give the path to my .css file or to my banner .png file, while using the webview->NavigateToString() function?

my code looks like this

```
std::stringstream output;
output << getDisplayHeaderWithBanner();
if (mRecivedAndParsedInternetData) {
 output << getDisplayText();
}
else {
 output << getDisplayErrorText();
}
output << getDisplayClosingHtml()

m_webview->NavigateToString(string2stringhat(output.str()));
```

This code shows the text but without the gfx or the right css.

I found the msdn example for this case, but i don´t understand this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx

Comment: Maybe replace `src="myFile.css"` with `src="http://myServer.com/myFile.css"` ?

Comment: its a good idea. But getting the .css from online server is no way. The .css file is already on the device and i want to reuse this. So `src="ms-appx:///myFile.css` whould be good, but this isn't working for me.

Comment: You can embedded your CSS styles in the page, e.g.,  `<style>.style1 { /*  ... */ } .style2 { /*  ... */ } </style>` in the `<head>` of your **html** document.

Comment: this would be possible for me. but then i have the same problem with my gfx (in my case i use only one banner.png)

Comment: You can also embed images: http://www.techerator.com/2011/12/how-to-embed-images-directly-into-your-html/

Comment: WinRT does not support embed local files in html build by string, is not allowed for security reasons [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/3e759487-ea22-4ea6-8096-ff013fb099fd/how-to-load-a-local-htmlfile-into-webview). Finaly I get it by inline .css and embeded image (load file, decode it to base64 string, add it). Thanks a lot kiewic for your help.